# MySQL - LEFT JOIN with GROUP_CONCAT with 3 tables - unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to join 3 tables and do a GROUP_CONCAT, but get

```
Unknown column 'program_outcome.program_outcome_pk' in 'field list'
```

Query:

```
SELECT program_outcome.program_outcome_pk, 
       program_outcome.program_outcome, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_pk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome) unit_outcomes 
FROM   program_outcome po 
       LEFT JOIN program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup pouo 
               ON po.program_outcome_pk = pouo.program_outcome_fk
       LEFT JOIN unit_outcome uo 
               ON pouo.unit_outcome_fk = uo.unit_outcome_pk 
GROUP  BY po.program_outcome_pk, 
          po.program_outcome
```

The results that I'm looking for are like:

```
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| program_outcome.program_outcome  |  unit_outcome.unit_outcome                       |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| program outcome 1                | unit_outcome 2, unit_outcome 5                   |
| program outcome 2                | unit_outcome 7, unit_outcome 1                   |
| program outcome 3                | unit_outcome 1, unit_outcome 9, unit_outcome 11  |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f940eb1a299657887bfea8c0d19a74bd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the aliases since your tables doesn't have conflicting names, here is a working Query based on your fiddle:

```
SELECT program_outcome_pk, 
       program_outcome, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome_pk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome) unit_outcomes 
FROM   program_outcome po 
       LEFT JOIN program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup pouo 
               ON po.program_outcome_pk = pouo.program_outcome_fk
       LEFT JOIN unit_outcome uo 
               ON pouo.unit_outcome_fk = uo.unit_outcome_pk 
GROUP  BY po.program_outcome_pk, 
          po.program_outcome
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the aliases you defined in your `from` and `join` claues:

```sql
SELECT po.program_outcome_pk, 
       po.program_outcome, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(pouo.unit_outcome_fk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(uo.unit_outcome) unit_outcomes 
FROM   program_outcome po 
       LEFT JOIN program_outcome_unit_outcome_lookup pouo 
               ON po.program_outcome_pk = pouo.program_outcome_fk
       LEFT JOIN unit_outcome uo 
               ON pouo.unit_outcome_fk = uo.unit_outcome_pk 
GROUP  BY po.program_outcome_pk, 
          po.program_outcome
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an unknown column on pouo.unit_outcome_pk

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a4e477db1fff649a94b08f902cc482f2

Comment: @Tenderfoot Looking at the fiddle you provided (thanks BTW), there just isn't a column called `unit_outcome_pk` in that table. It's `unit_outcome_fk`. I've edited my answer accordingly.